# How to output all of the inputs before exiting the program in hackerrank

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, output

We are required to pass our code in hackerrank but my program exits right after encountering an error instead of printing the inputs first.

Here is my code:

```
                #START INPUTS
try:
    start_month = int(input('Enter start month: '))
    assert 1 <= (start_month) <= 12

    start_day = int(input('Enter start day: '))
    assert 1 <= (start_day) <= 31

    start_year = int(input('Enter start year: '))
    if (start_month == 2) and (start_day == 29):
        assert (1971 <= (start_year) <= 2020) and (start_year % 400 == 0 or start_year % 4 == 0 and start_year % 100 != 0)
    else:
        assert 1971 <= (start_year) <= 2020



                    #END INPUTS
    end_month = int(input('Enter end month: '))
    assert 1 <= (end_month) <= 12

    end_day = int(input('Enter end day: '))
    assert 1 <= (end_day) <= 31

    end_year = int(input('Enter end year: '))
    if (end_month == 2) and (end_day == 29):
        assert (start_year <= end_year <= 2020) and (end_year % 400 == 0 or end_year % 4 == 0 and end_year % 100 != 0)
    else:
        assert start_year <= (end_year) <= 2020
except:
    print('')
    print('Invalid Input. Exiting Program.')
    exit()
```

Here is my result:
[image]

The test case 6 is almost the same as test case 5.

Answer (score 0):

You should make assertions after all inputs are **given**. Try that:

```py
try:
           # Inputs
    start_month = int(input('Enter start month: '))
    start_day = int(input('Enter start day: '))
    start_year = int(input('Enter start year: '))
    end_month = int(input('Enter end month: '))
    end_day = int(input('Enter end day: '))
    end_year = int(input('Enter end year: '))

          #start input assertions

    assert 1 <= (start_month) <= 12
    assert 1 <= (start_day) <= 31
    if (start_month == 2) and (start_day == 29):
        assert (1971 <= (start_year) <= 2020) and (start_year % 400 == 0 or start_year % 4 == 0 and start_year % 100 != 0)
    else:
        assert 1971 <= (start_year) <= 2020

            #end input assertions
    assert 1 <= (end_month) <= 12
    assert 1 <= (end_day) <= 31
    if (end_month == 2) and (end_day == 29):
        assert (start_year <= end_year <= 2020) and (end_year % 400 == 0 or end_year % 4 == 0 and end_year % 100 != 0)
    else:
        assert start_year <= (end_year) <= 2020
except:
    print('')
    print('Invalid Input. Exiting Program.')
    exit()
```

Comment: it still fails whenever the input is not an integer